# How to us ng-Repeat for angular translate for array objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angular-translate

I am currently working on an Angular project with the plugin angular translate from Pascal Precht. I have an FAQ page which has a tabs for answer. What I want to achieve is to have a dynamic values for questions. So that I will just have a loop for those questions and those questions will be in a translation file as Json array. here is my sample json file.

```
"FAQS_QUESTION"  : [
   {
     "question" : "Question 1?",
     "answer"   : "Answer 1 "
   },
   {
     "question" : "Question 2?",
     "answer"   : "Answer 2" 
   },
   {
     "question" : "Question 3?",
     "answer"   : "Answer 3" 
   }
]
```

I tried the code below but it is not working. I get a "angular.js:14525 Translation for FAQS_QUESTION doesn't exist"

```
ul( ng-repeat="thumbnail in 'FAQS_QUESTION' | translate ")
   li 
       | {{thumbnail.question}}
       | {{thumbnail.answer}}
```

I Also tried loading it in my Controller with no luck

```
$translate('FAQS_QUESTION').then(function (translations) {
    console.log(translations.questions);
}, function (translationIds) {
    console.log(translationIds);
});
```

I found a workaround and the implementation is like this:

```
ul(ng-init="count = ('FAQS_QUESTION_COUNT' | translate)")
  li(ng-repeat="item in getQuestionCount(count) track by $index")
     p(translate="FAQS_QUESTION.{{$index}}.question")
     p(translate="FAQS_QUESTION.{{$index}}.answer")
```

It solves my problem. But it will be a tedious for maintenance to indicate the count for each Iteration. Since we are planning to have a section for each quetions

Can anyone help me for the workaround for this one? I am not sure I appreciate all your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet

```
ul( ng-repeat="thumbnail in 'FAQS_QUESTION' | translate ")
   li 
       | {{thumbnail.question}}
       | {{thumbnail.answer}}
```

your value `'FAQS_QUESTION'` is just a plain string, so you're not referencing your data. Also, the `translate`-filter doesn't work with collections i believe.

Instead, try doing something like this:

```
ul( ng-repeat="thumbnail in FAQS_QUESTION")
   li 
       | {{thumbnail.question | translate}}
       | {{thumbnail.answer | translate}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes have also tried this but it does not show any data.

Comment: Do you have a variable called `FAQS_QUESTION` in your scope? Could you share a bit of the controller?

Comment: Nope, this variable is in my translation Json.

Comment: Then just replace `FAQS_QUESTION` with the scope variable you've assigned your translation json. I assume you've loaded this json into an angular controller somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I have loaded the json in a module config. `$translateProvider
  .useStaticFilesLoader({
   prefix: '//'+STORAGE_DOMAIN+'/'+STORAGE_CONTAINER+'/locale-',
   suffix: '.json'
  })
  .preferredLanguage('en')
  .useLocalStorage()`

Comment: If I have declared it like that, how will I access the value for the FAQS_QUESTIONS? I tried using the $translate().then() function but it returns an error " Translation for FAQS_QUESTION doesn't exist"

Comment: You need an array containing your translation keys. You must do something of the sort in `getQuestionCount()`, could you share that?

Comment: For that one, it is just return an array with the count of how many iterations I would make. `$scope.getQuestionCount =function(num){
       return new Array(parseInt(num));
    }`

Comment: The fourth code on my post is my current implementation which is working fine. But I want the data to be flexible and doesn't need force iterations. If I can get the values of a json array from angular-translate and put it in a scope to iterate for ng-repeat, it will be great. This will lessen the burden for maintaining the data for that one. The users can add as many questions they like without modifying the code.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do here is beyond the intended use of the translation library. It's meant to do single translations of plain strings, whereas you want to iterate over a collection of strings in a specified language. You could instead take a different approach, where you simply load your json using the `$http`-service and then just load a different file according to the selected language.

Comment: I see. I will try the approach you suggested. Thank you so much for your insights. :)